# HTML/jQuery Preloading images

Tags: jquery, html

I'm upgrading a basic photo gallery to use jQuery (woohoo!).

I understand the semantics of jQuery thus far, with one exception: I can't seem to wrap my brain around this whole preloading of images thing. I already have a layout complete with divs classes and ids.

Here's roughly what the image part looks like:

```
<div id="main">
<img id="spotHolder" src="images/somePic.jpg">
</div>
<div id="others">
<img class="otherPics" src="images/someOtherPic.jpg">
</div>
```

I was using a [jQuery Howto](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html) as a guide for preloading images; but I don't know what I would need to do (if anything?) to the html.

Looking for an idea of what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would need to do anything to the HTML...  To preload all images possible at once you could use:

```
$("img").attr('src', function (_, src) {
    $("<img>").attr('src', src);
});
```

It would probably be a bit heavy-handed to do this, so you could use a more specific selector:

```
$("#gallery-container img").attr('src' /* etc. */
```

Comment: I appreciate that you took the time to give me an explanation and example - really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look on this very page, a little farther over to the right (in the "Related" section), you'll see an exact duplicate of your question that just might answer it for you:

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: Well I'd already seen that question, but I read a little farther and found something that definitely fits: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10214021/1301332 so thanks!